# Cleanup of command buffers (and resources) after barrier-based synchronization; but the validation layers still complain

Tags: vulkan, validation-layers

This is a specific question about barrier-based synchronization w.r.t. command buffer submission and cleanup of resources that are required by the command buffers (like used buffers and images).

Let's assume, everything is on a single queue and there are three frames in flight.

I perform the following operations:

```
Create Render-CmdBfr[0..2], Fence[0..2]
...
Create StagingBuffer
Create Image
Create Init-CmdBfr
Record `copy StagingBuffer to Image` into Init-CmdBuffer
Record `barrier ALL_COMMANDS ALL_COMMANDS MEMORY_WRITE MEMORY_READ` into Init-CmdBuffer
Submit Init-CmdBuffer without any semaphore or fence
...
// Frame #1
Submit Render-CmdBfr[0] -> signal Fence[0]
// Frame #2
Submit Render-CmdBfr[1] -> signal Fence[1]
// Frame #3
Submit Render-CmdBfr[2] -> signal Fence[2] 
// Frame #4
Wait for Fence[0] -> submit Render-CmdBfr[0] -> signal Fence[0] 
Delete Init-CmdBfr
Delete Image
Delete StagingBuffer
// Frame #5
Wait for Fence[1] -> submit Render-CmdBfr[1] -> signal Fence[1]     
// Frame #6
Wait for Fence[2] -> submit Render-CmdBfr[2] -> signal Fence[2] 
... continue forever ...
```

The problematic part is where I delete `Init-CmdBfr`, `Image`, and `StagingBuffer`. Or actually, it is not problematic insofar as the application works just fine. But the validation layer complains:

> Vk-callback with Id[0|VUID-vkFreeCommandBuffers-pCommandBuffers-00047] and Message[Attempt to free VkCommandBuffer 0x20e61cff060[] which is in use. The Vulkan spec states: All elements of pCommandBuffers must not be in the pending state (https://www.khronos.org/registry/vulkan/specs/1.1-extensions/html/vkspec.html#VUID-vkFreeCommandBuffers-pCommandBuffers-00047)]

Also further messages emerge, e.g. like the following:

> Vk-callback with Id[0|VUID-vkDestroyBuffer-buffer-00922] and Message[Cannot free VkBuffer 0xe6bc0400000000a1[] that is in use by a command buffer. The Vulkan spec states: All submitted commands that refer to buffer, either directly or via a VkBufferView, must have completed execution (https://www.khronos.org/registry/vulkan/specs/1.1-extensions/html/vkspec.html#VUID-vkDestroyBuffer-buffer-00922)]

The spec states that a command buffer can only be deleted when it has left the "pending" state. Through my `barrier ALL_COMMANDS ALL_COMMANDS MEMORY_WRITE MEMORY_READ` and the full cycle of `Fence[0]` signal and wait, this **must** be given in frame #4 in my opinion.

My first question is: Am I right about this assumption? And, is this approach of mine okay?

My second question is: If I am right and my approach is okay, how can I prevent the validation layers from complaining?

I think, the validation layers just do not know about the barrier and complain because it could have been that I haven't created a barrier. Indeed, when I add a semaphore to the submission of `Init-CmdBfr` (i.e. `Submit Init-CmdBuffer and signal Init-Semaphore`), the validation layers do not complain anymore. But the semaphore is actually unnecessary in my opinion. Can it be done without it?

**Update:**

Replaced all `Semaphore[i]` with `Fence[i]` to illustrate my problem better. (The previous example led to some confusion, sorry.)

Comment: "*Submit Init-CmdBuffer without any semaphore or fence*" How do you know when it's done?

Comment: By the use of a barrier, I know that all commands of `Init-CmdBfr` must have finished before the `Render-CmdBfr[0]` starts executing (on the same queue). And I know when `Render-CmdBfr[0]` is done because it signals a semaphore. At least that's how I think it is working, but I could be wrong.

Comment: "*By the use of a barrier*" Barriers synchronize with subsequent commands, not with out-of-queue processes. That's what semaphores are for.

Comment: Yes, but isn't it a perfectly valid implicit synchronization dependency in the example which I have described above? `Init-CmdBfr` -> barrier -> `Render-CmdBfr[0]` -> semaphore -> safe to delete `Init-CmdBfr`.

Comment: My point is that the *barrier* is meaningless. It doesn't offer any useful synchronization with regard to the validity of destroying the command buffer.

Comment: But that's exactly my question: If I *omit* the barrier then yes, I do not know when I may destroy the command buffer. However, if I *add* the barrier, then I know exactly when I can delete the command buffer due to the dependencies detailed above. Only the validation layers do not know it... or I am overlooking something. So in my opinion, the barrier is not meaningless at all, isn't it?

Comment: Why do you believe the barrier needs to be there? Pipeline barriers represent execution dependencies between *commands*; deleting a CB is not a "command".

Comment: Yes, deleting a command buffer is not a command. But that's not what I meant. I meant the following: **Case 1)** Without the barrier, I simply can not know when it is safe to delete `Init-CmdBfr`. I would have to use a semaphore or fence in that case. I fully agree with you on this. However: **Case 2)** *With* the barrier (as described above in the example), I know that `Init-CmdBfr` finishes before `Render-CmdBfr[0]`. Therefore, it is safe to delete `Init-CmdBfr` after `Render-CmdBfr[0]`'s semaphore has been signalled.

Comment: "*With the barrier ... I know that Init-CmdBfr finishes before Render-CmdBfr[0]*" How do you know that? Show me the part of the specification that states that a barrier at the end of a command buffer has some special meaning with regard to whether that CB is still being utilized.

Comment: Seems after the update that should work because of `Wait for Fence[0]`. Assuming `Init-CmdBfr` is submitted to the same queue as `Render-CmdBfr[0]`. Still, pseudocode can be deceiving. I assume if you add `vkQueueWaitIdle` that it stops complaining?

Answer (score 1):

Barriers define the order of execution of commands. They have no effect on the completion status of command *buffers*. In your example, it is possible for `Init-CmdBfr` to still be in the "pending" state even though `Render-CmdBfr` has begun executing. Barriers don't change that.

A command buffer is considered to have completed execution only when the specification says that it has. And the specification only lays down two mechanisms for denoting when a a CB has completed:

1. The queue submit operation it was submitted as a part of signals a fence
2. The batch it is a part of signals a semaphore.

That's *it*. If you need to know if a CB has completed, then you must use one of these two mechanisms to detect this. And (binary) semaphores cannot be waited on by the CPU, not unless you convert them into a mutex or something. So your choices are timeline semaphores or fences.

Comment: ad 1: I think you can infer CB has finished execution via submission order, or through swapchain images. But yea, there has to be a fence at some point that is waited on.